# Netty Multicasting Setup

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I am trying to use netty 4.1 for LAN discovery in a school project I'm doing, where one instance of my program("server" later) joins a hard-coded multicast group and sends a status `DatagramPacket` to that group every second, and another instance of my program("client" later) joins that same group and receives those packets. The server does join the group and does send the packets to that group, and I can see those packets in the data capture in WireShark on other devices, but no channelRead events are fired in the client's `NioDatagramChannel`, unless the server and the client are on the same device.
I couldn't find any good/recent examples of multicasting with netty, and I can't come up with a way to approach this.

Here's my setup of a multicaster, which is the same for both client and server:

```
{
group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
  try {
      Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap()
              .group(group)
              .channelFactory((ChannelFactory<NioDatagramChannel>) () -> new NioDatagramChannel(InternetProtocolFamily.IPv4))
              .localAddress(Multiplayer.localIp, groupAddress.getPort())
              .option(ChannelOption.IP_MULTICAST_IF, Multiplayer.networkInterface)
              .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
              .handler(new ServerDiscoverer(servers));
      ch = (NioDatagramChannel) b.bind(groupAddress.getPort()).sync().channel();
      ch.joinGroup(groupAddress, Multiplayer.networkInterface).addListener(future ->
              logger.info("Listening for servers on " + groupAddress.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ':' + groupAddress.getPort()
                      + " on interface " + Multiplayer.networkInterface.getDisplayName())).sync();
      if (isServer) {
          startBroadcast();
      }
      ch.closeFuture().sync().addListener(future -> logger.info("Closing multicast channel"));
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
      group.shutdownGracefully();
  }      
}
```

`Multiplayer.localIp` should be the ip address assigned to the device by the router, and `Multiplayer.networkInterface` should be an interface that is interacting with the local area. `groupAddress` is the hard-coded multicast address used by my program.
I expected `channelRead0` to fire on the `ServerDiscoverer` instance passed into `.handler()`, but it only does when the server is run on the same machine as the client.
I really hope that there is just a problem with this setup, because otherwise I have absolutely no idea of what to look at next. Basically, my questions are: is there anything obviously wrong with the code above? What problem could cause the `channelRead0` to only trigger if the server and the client are on the same machine?

Edit: I got confused with how my firewall was set up, after re-checking it I added some permissions and everything worked. The code itself did not require many of the bootstrap options I used.

Comment: Added new options, 'ChannelOption.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP_DISABLED, true' and 'ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST,true'. According to [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/socketOpt.html) those are needed, but I cannot test this as I do not have access to two separate devices at the moment

Comment: Double check java is added to your firewall if you are using Windows. Windows doe snot allow you to receive traffic to a multicast group if the program does not allows incoming connections in the firewall